# Twilio voicemail with worker order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I am trying to implement a voicemail with twilio, for that reason I created a worker that will be the final assignment and it will redirect to a Twiml voicemail endpoint.
Problem is that my taskrouter does not assign the incoming call to my virtual user although it's the only one available.
[image]

And here is the workflow.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the voicemail worker had a task assigned so it couldn't get another assignment.